# What is the physical interpretation of a differential equation?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, differentiation, differential-equations

I would like to learn more about differential equations and their interpretation. I know the derivation rules, but I fail big time in interpreting and understanding the functionality of them. For this, I have formulated a basic example with displacement and velocity (two parameters that I can relate to):

$$\dfrac{dx_{tot}(t)}{dt}=\dfrac{dx_1(t)}{dt}-\dfrac{dx_2(t)}{dt}\tag{1}$$

where $x_{tot}$ was the total distance that change with time, $x_1$ was one distance and $x_2$ was another distance. Let's say that the two functions look like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what Eq. 1 does? What is the physical interpretation of such an equation? What would $x_{tot}$ mean? How would it look if one would plot it?

Comment: I think it's all about the *rate of change*

Comment: It is totally unclear how $x_1$ and $x_2$ relate to each other (if they do).  If your question is about the meaning of a derivative, in general, then you should spend time studying the definition of a derivative. While important, don't focus so much on the "limit" part, but focus on the ratio part.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positions of two objects, $x_{tot}$ could be $x_1 - x_2$, which is their relative position, and $\frac{dx_{tot}}{dt}$ their relative velocity.

Comment: What about x2? it seems to reach infinite velocity and also travel back in time.

Comment: The graph itself that you posted appears poorly drawn, hence the confusion. It stems from that weird bump right near the "x2" label. From this graph, it appears that x2 has more than one position at that time, which is just nonsense for any real-world system.

Comment: I have added a slightly better plot, sorry for that.

Comment: @AlbertAspect I assumed that was a drawing artifact. If those features were important, the OP would have emphasised them.